# Can extensive exception logging cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in my production server.

The only thing which I noticed in the log file is that there are too many full stacked trace exceptions thrown by a method which is not able to find some id (which is part of business logic).

I'm using `org.slf4j` for logging.

So my question is - can extensive logging cause this issue or I should be focusing on some other parts to check the memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

For anything like this you need real information not guesses. Use a profiler (Netbeans and most other IDEs have one built in) and that can tell you exactly where the memory has gone. For what it's worth unless you have something very odd in your setup logging is unlikely to cause the issue. Whatever happened in the exception though may (or may not) be connected.

Answer (score 1):

Logging, extensive as it may be, only involves short-lived objects, which will reach the Old Generation only in extreme cases. On the other hand, a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error means that practically all of the heap is strongly reachable and there is just a tiny bit of objects to reclaim on it. The GC must work hard to identify those few objects, and must do so very often.

Therefore your extensive logging may *contribute* to your problem and exacerbate it, but it will almost never be its true source. You must find what is permanently occupying your heap.